# wiremock soap ws-policy support?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, xml-dsig, wiremock

I am wondering if anybody knows if wiremock has support for WS-Policy in regards to SOAP webservices?

What I'm after is to give wiremock a WSDL that has some WS-Policy in it, that contains the "reciepe" for what the response should look like. Ie timestamp in the header, signed body, etc.

So, ideally I'd just specify the soap body and wiremock would apply the WS-Policy and add the necessary signatures.

I found this [github issue](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/168) that mentioned SOAP support, but the impression I got from that support was that it was just an arbitrary text response without having actual SOAP understanding/processing.

Would it be possible to plug-in Apache CXF to get proper JAX-WS/WS-Policy support if I were so inclined?  Or would it be difficult to offload response processing to a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

No such support I'm afraid. SOAP requires a lot of tooling to in test contexts.

[I posted my solution to this problem in another similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202603/369930) The crux of it was some hand crafted SOAP manipulation and WireMocks CustomRequest matchers.