# How to generate mock web service using WSDL in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, mocking

I have WSDL file and for local testing I need to generate mock web service.

**Please do not recommend SoapUI**.

Can anybody please help how to generate **mock web service in Java using WSDL**?

Comment: You can generate the clientside java classes from WSDL using www.easywsdl.com but generating a whole web service is a completely different thing...

Comment: @Shark, client side i have already developed.now i need to generate mock web service

Comment: Upvote for the 'please do not recommend SOAPUI'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to create a Web Services project using an IDE.
This will allow you to create a mock service and also implement your business logic.

As an example, using Eclipse:

Before starting, ensure that:

- Eclipse has a server installed (Apache Tomcat)
- Your WSDL file have a .wsdl extension (if not, rename as .wsdl)

Now, start Eclipse:

1. Create a new java "Dynamic Web Project"
2. Create a folder WebContent\wsdl and copy your WSDL file
3. Right-click on project > select new "Web Service"
4. Select:

   - Web Service type: "Top down Java bean Web Service"
   - Service definition: browser your WSDL file
   - Select "Start Service"
   - Select "Java Proxy / Start Client"
   - Select both option at the bottom of the form (publish/monitor)
5. Click next to complete process

At the end, your server should be started and WS deployed - check that your WSDL is available.

Now, you can:

- call your WS using Eclipse Web Services Explorer [see explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMCfP.png)
- implement your WS mockup business logic [see method implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apez7.png)
- or use a working java client to call your WS programmatically

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wiremock. However you will be needing to create and structure json/xml files according to your need. 
 This will give you an better idea. [Using WireMock with SOAP Web Services in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974249/using-wiremock-with-soap-web-services-in-java)