# Soap web services mocking using wiremock

Tags: web-services, soap, mocking, wiremock

I am new to soap, wiremock.
Can anyone suggest how to go about mocking soap service using wiremock starting with just wsdl and xsd files ??

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WireMock with SOAP Web Services in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974249/using-wiremock-with-soap-web-services-in-java)

Comment: @yassadi can u provide a example of it ??

Comment: @yassadi for all the questions related to `how to mock soap web services with wiremock` the link you send above is the most recommended, but its doesn't provide a full example. There is a way to convert a `Pojo` into `Soap Request/Reponse` like with `json.simple` ? What is the Content-type with Soap, `xml` or `xml/soap`. Can you please provide some details?